# What is the name of this kind of pattern/component?

Tags: scrolling, scrollbars, component, patterns

[image]

I would like to know what this approach is called. In case my incredibly high-fidelity mockups are too confusing, what I'm after is a design that explicitly links the thumb to the viewport by drawing a filled area linking the top of the thumb to the top of the content and the bottom of the content to the bottom of the thumb, thereby highlighting the connection between content and proportion of content visible compared to the total content available. I have seen various versions of this but can't put my finger on any.

[Edit] Just to be clear. Obviously I know what a standard scroll/viewport combo is and looks like. I'm after this variation which explicitly links content to thumb using a graphical device which in the case of my diagrams is the light grey polygon running from the edges of the content to the edges of the thumbnail bar.

Comment: Just to be clear: I gather that your scroll bar really is a column of thumbnails or something like that?

Comment: @André No its a continuous block of content. Probably text but could be a chart or like.

Comment: @André Sorry. I see what you mean. I suppose it could be a series of pages,

Comment: I don't get the question.  I assume you already know what a scrollbar is and how it is used. Is your problem how  you visualize the relationship between a scrollbar and the scroll view in a mockup?

Comment: The important part of the component is the grey polygon drawn between bar and content that makes the relationship between the bar and the content explicit.

Comment: Where have you seen this?  Could you point out some real world examples?  I don't believe I've ever seen such a visualization.  Thus - I doubt there is a general pattern/name to describe this...

Comment: Have a look at http://www.tchibo.de/ - when you scroll down there's a thumbnail scrollbar on the right that shows which part of the thumbnail is visible on the screen... Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Gabriele That's not it, but very interesting none-the-less. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the value of this. The size of the scrollbar typically shows this relation without the need of the gray part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.tchibo.de/. When you scroll down something similar is used; it's called a visual scrollbar or preview scrollbar. It shows the position of the main window content on a thumbnail of the very long page content.

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I like that pattern a lot

Answer (score 2):

[As I said in my comment: I'm not sure if I've seen such a visualization before...](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/19688/what-is-the-name-of-this-kind-of-pattern-component#comment27200_19688)

The closes concept I can think of, is **"linking lines"** and **"synchronization links"** used in various comparison tools.

Screenshot from [Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge/topic_comparison_synchronization_links.html):
[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's a good example of something similar, but not the pattern I'm after. That's half the problem. I've definitely seen it before but I can't remember where.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description, it's an abstraction of a **Magnifying glass**.

The abstract content is small (whether or not its shown on the viewport) and the viewport is used in such a way as to give the user a sense that they're seeing an enlarged version of the content in much the same way that a pop-in of an enlarged image can be used over a thumbnail to give a magnifying effect.

Comment: Nice thinking. Yes It is a kind of magnifying glass i suppose.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge this would be called a "Long rectangular scrollbar" or a "Conventional scrollbar". This pattern has been around since the begining of GUI (Beware! This is the opinion of the writer, not a fact). It first saw daylight in 1984 ([Steve Jobs introduction of Macintosh](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0FtgZNOD44)) if I remember correct.

---

References:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrollbar
 http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Mobile_Design_Pattern:_Scrollbar

Comment: Ha. I was wondering what the purpose of the bar on the right of the browser window was. I've never been able to work out how to read text below the fold before. But seriously; the important part of the pattern is the way that the relationship between the content and the thumb/total content is represented graphically (by the grey polygon in my example).

Comment: I think the point is that the SIZE Of the scrollbar already communicates that. The gray part seems redundant (if not confusing)

Comment: @DA01 In most scrollbars, the ratio between thumb and bar is the same as the ratio between total content and the size of the viewport (though this often becomes skewed by there being a minimum height for the thumb). However there is no explicit visual link between thumb and viewport. Its really frustrating as without an example its hard to explain, but without an example no-one quite understands.

Comment: "However there is no explicit visual link between thumb and viewport" = while that is true, I think it's implied. It's how the scrollbar has worked for nearly 3 decades of GUIs. Not that the gray part may not be interesting--just saying it's not typical and perhaps redundant in many situations.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're talking about a simple preview, like they have on youtube on mouseover on the video's progress bar.

[image]

Comment: No. The important part of this component is the fact it explicitly shows the relationship between content and bar using (in my example) a grey polygon which describes how the content is related to the thumb and total amount of content represented by the bar.

Comment: What do you mean by 'thumb'?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a name for this - at least not one that means the same thing to many people.

I understand that you mean the mechanism whereby the relationship between the content and the scrollbar is highlighted by the linking polygon but the linking is implicit through familiarity of scrollbar behaviour and your example is not widely used enough to warrant it's own pattern name.

Thus you might [find a few mentions in research papers](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.129.1933&rep=rep1&type=pdf) or find localised terms depending on the application or ui toolkit being used, but certainly not a term which is generally accepted.

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds most similar to the 'navigator' function in Photoshop. It is a small viewport that outlines the visible area of a much larger plane.  In the attached image it is the small red rectangle that shows the visible area of the whole image.

update: I cannot yet post images because my rep is too low. Why doesn't it extend across Stack Exchange sites? Anyway - look it up in Photoshop.

Comment: if you link your SE accounts, you get a 100 rep boost.

Comment: Negatory - SE knows my accounts are linked because I'm getting inbox messages from UX and Stackoverflow in the header bar. Maybe it takes time to add the 100 boost?

Comment: Might only work on initial signup?  [I just did this on math.se without problem or delay](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/28940/peteorpeter?tab=reputation).

Answer (score 0):

If you have visual studio 2010 and install the 'Productivity Power Tools' extension it includes an 'Enhanced scroll bar' option that is very similar to what you describe.

[image: Fancy scroll bar]

The small blurry text in the center is a scroll bar and the scroll thumb is the back bordered (cut off at the top) vertically aligned rectangle, which surrounds the text that is visible on your screen at that time. The blue dot in the bar shows where the cursor currently is, and the magnified preview (the horizontal rectangle with the normal sized text) appears when you mouse over the scroll bar to show you a preview of what is there.

There is also an alternate view that does away with the blurry text and returns the scroll bar to its normal size, but you still get the mouse over preview. They called it 'Map Mode' and the other one 'Full Mode'